# Java Generic Cast Error

Tags: java

I've got an issue in java that I don't understand, could someone explain me that strange behaviour?

my code :

```
package com.test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class MyTest extends TestCase{

    class Container<I, J extends I> {
        protected J data;

        public J getData() {
            return data;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void setData(I data) {
            try {
                this.data = (J) data;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                System.err.println("Cast" + e);
            }
        }
    }

    class A {
        public String a = "A";
    }

    class B extends A {
        public String B = "B";
    }

    class C extends A {
        public String C = "C";
    }

    public void test1() throws Exception{
        Container<A, B> container = new Container<>();
        container.setData(new C());
        assertNull(container.getData());
    }
}
```

I expected this test to pass, but I've got this following error :

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Expected: <null> but was: com.test.MyTest$C@5c228bbd
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:57)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:22)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:277)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:268)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.assertNull(TestCase.java:438)
    at com.test.MyTest.test1(MyTest.java:39)
```

How is it possible that the container can contain a C class into a B class?

Also, if I try to get the B value from the data, I've got a ClassCastException...

```
public void test1() throws Exception{
    Container<A, B> container = new Container<>();
    container.setData(new C());
    System.out.println(container.getData().B);
}
```

Executing that test gives this following error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.MyTest$C cannot be cast to com.test.MyTest$B
    at com.test.MyTest.test1(MyTest.java:39)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  The generic constaints are only for compile-time checks (which your code passes).  Once your code is compiled, the `I` and `J` generic types are substituted for `Object` in the resulting code.

So the running code really looks like:

```
public void setData(Object data) {
    try {
        this.data = (Object) data; //Obviously always works!
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        System.err.println("Cast" + e);  //This line never reached
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that, I will surround this cast with a test using instanceof instead of the try catch

Comment: @aurélienlemaitre No...just change the signature to `setData(J data)`. You're killing the point of generics here

Comment: Whoops, I cannot use the `instanceof` neither, But I still need the signature I used... How can I handle bad cast without `instanceof` or `try catch`?

Comment: Why do you need to pass an `I` but store a `J` ?

Comment: Cause I work with guice and use a provider that instantiate a `J` but return me an `I`, And I would like to avoid making the cast test everywhere I use the setData (almost everywhere in the application). Unfortunately, more I think about it, more I feel that I will have te refactor all my code to remove the generics because I will never be able to handle the ClassCastExeption that could rises...

Comment: Well I did not see your code but you won't achiveve anything like that. If it's short enough, you can put it on a gist and I can take a look at it

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't suppress compile-time warnings, otherwise you cannot be surprised that your code has a strange runtime behaviour. Your cast in `setData` is unchecked because of type erasure, it means it will **never** fail. If you want a `J` to be passed, just use `J` in the signature instead of `I`. The type consistency will be ensured compile-time.

By the way, `assertNull` was not the right way to test this behaviour. You should have let the `ClassCastException` propagate and use JUnit annotations :

```
@Test(expected = ClassCastException.class)
public void test1() {
    Container<A, B> container = new Container<>();
    container.setData(new C());
}
```